# how to fix external HDD become 1.0KB shortcut

Tags: windows, anti-virus, virus

When i open my external hdd, all i can see is just 1.0kb shortcut that is the same name as my external hdd and when i click it i would redirect me all my files. even my flashdrive is experiencing the same. anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

**[Voted to migrate to superuser]**

All your files are probably "super-hidden" . 
Open a `cmd` window and run `attrib -s -h *` on that directory.
It probably occurred because of malware.

Some common variants of **[Sality](http://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2006-011714-3948-99)** do this. Use the removal tool.